Consider non singular matrices made up of same entries having same determinant, are they all equivalent through some sequence of row and column swap?
Suppose I have the matrix,
$$\begin{bmatrix} a &b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$
Now, consider another matrix made up of same elements.
$$\begin{bmatrix} d &c \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$$
This one above is also built up of same elements and has same determinant. Here  we can map between the matrix by a row swap followed by a column swap (order doesn't matter).
Is that generally true tho? Can non singular matrix built up of same elements which have same determinant be turned into each other by row / column swaps?

The motivation comes from some me trying to solve  this question: Counting non singular matrices

Consider a 3×3 matrix and the a11 entry and a22 entry of it. They can't be put in the same row and same column by any row swap or column swap.

They are still not in the same row or column right, so if you take a 3×3 matrix A with 1s in a11 and a22 and 0 elsewhere and another 3×3 matrix B with 1s in a11 and a12 and 0 elsewhere then you can't get B from A by row/column swiping

Ok, my mistake. You are correct. But, how does your point relate to the question? I believe that if you do such a swap, then you will neccesarily change the determinant @SoumikMukherjee

@trystwithfreedom You won't as the determinant of both matrices is 0

@Math101 What if I strengthen to only consider those with non zero determinant

consider $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1.5 & 2\ 0 & 3 & 1\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 1\ 0 & 1.5 & 1\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$

I'll check in a bit. Have some homework to do. @SoumikMukherjee

What about $\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{d&b\cr c&a\cr}$?

In general it is false for example for the above counterexample. But I wonder if it holds for symmetric matrices..

@SoumikMukherjee no, because for $b=c$ it is the result of a row and then a column switch

@Exodd oh right, I missed that, thanks

To give an answer that meets all the requirements, even the requirement suggested in the comments that both matrices be symmetric,
$$
\pmatrix{4&3&2\cr3&9&0\cr2&0&0\cr}\ {\rm\ and\ }\ 
\pmatrix{9&2&3\cr2&4&0\cr3&0&0\cr}
$$
are both symmetric, have the same entries, and the same nonzero determinant, but you can't get from one to the other by a sequence of row swaps and column swaps.

good, but I was thinking. Is it true when instead of numbers we have variables? Take two symmetric matrices  of variables. If they have the same (polynomial) determinant, is it true that they are a row-column swapped version of each other?
